# Where in firebase console is the initialize firestore config information

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have been going round and round in circles trying to find where the

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###'
});
```

data is located.

Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't created your instance yet, go to console.firebase.google.com and select the project you want to set up use with Firebase.

From there, select the type of project from the following screen (select web app):

[image]

The overlay will show your connection information.

If you've already created your project and are using Authorization, go to the console, click on Authorization, and you'll see "Web Setup" on the upper right side. Click that to get the same overlay.

Or, alternatively, you can get the field values by clicking on the settings icon next to "Project Overview" on the Nav Bar and then click on Project Settings.

[image]

Comment: The snippet will also show when you click "Add Firebase to your web app" in the first screen.